# PNG with black BG and 30% opacity lighter than black bg?

Tags: android

Here's a screen shot of the issue.  This png icon with a black BG with 30% opacity looks right against a colored BG but lightens against a black BG.  Any reason why?

[image]

Clarification:  What's happening with the brown BG is expected, what's throwing me off is the performance against the black BG

Comment: you sure it actually is lightening? Could very well just be an optical illusion: http://web.mit.edu/persci/people/adelson/images/checkershadow/checkershadow_illusion4med.jpg

Comment: first off... plus 1 for your comment.  That was a possibility I hadn't considered.  But unfortunately it is lightening.  Using the color picker in photoshop shows that the circle's background against black is #4a4a4a which is a gray tone

Answer (score 1):

If you set a background with alpha it will take some info from the elements behind it, so the color will be changed. If you want to use a specific color you must use a background without alpha

Comment: but the element behind it is a black background, so why is it appearing lighter?

Comment: The black color is the lack of any other color so it does not apport any value to the background but the brown color is a combination of some color so it will generate a different combination.

Comment: yeah, against the brown I'm cool.  That's an example of what I expect to happen.  What's throwing me off is the performance against a black background